# How to clear and force request on subordinate jQuery UI Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have 2 autocomplete controls. Lets say that the first is *country* and second is *city*.
How can I clear value and displayed text in *city* when value in *country* is changed? List of cities is retrieved from server. If *country* is changed, list of cities should be discarded and new request should be made for list of cities when user starts to type something in *city* autocomplete. How to force such behaviour?

jQuery 1.7.1, UI 1.8.18

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create autocomplete of city again after city list is change. Your flow will be like this:

On state name change-> call ajax function to get city list from server -> build options and assign to city select element then execute following line again.

```
$("#city").combobox();
```

Hopefully you using combobox widget of autocomplete. Otherwise recreate source of autocomplete, better feth in json format only from server, like this:

```
 var availableTags = [
"NewCity1",
"NewCity2",
"NewCity3",
"NewCity4"
];

$( "#city" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a bit and this works for me:

```
hiddenInput.val(''); 

visibleInput.val(visibleInput.attr('placeholder')).addClass('WaterMarkedTextBox');
visibleInput.flushCache();
```

Both input fields are HTML elements that are created by *city* autocomplete.
Without `flushCache` call there was no new request for *empty* city value.